# how to create hyperlinks(<a></a>) in a paragraph of string, using Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a paragraph of string, which contains URL words as well, 
Like :

> "Hello world, **http://thymeleaf.org** and **https://google.com**
>   welcomes you."

**while generating PDF**, those 2 URL words should come as hyperlinks and rest of text should be plain.

Answer (score -1):

```
@ModelAttribute("paragrah")
public String getParagraph()
{
    return "Hello world, <a href='http://thymeleaf.org'>http://thymeleaf.org</a> and <a href='https://google.com'>https://google.com</a> welcomes you.";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p th:text="${paragraph}"/>
```